# What is the pattern of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I went though this pattern and I think the results might be interesting. It was a long one but I'm only showing the first five (to make things look simpler).

$$0,1,a+b,a^2 + b^2 + \frac 32ab , \frac52\left[\frac{a^3}2 + \frac{b^3}2 + ab(a+b)\right] \ldots$$

If you write it on paper, it may actually resemble with $(a+b)^2$, and so on but I did not get anything with it. Also, it is not a sequence with a lot of constants, so solving this might get ugly, I believe...

Comment: What rule gives the pattern?  If you have more terms, it would be good to show them.  Typesetting them in $\LaTeX$-see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) to get started-will also make it much easier to read.

Comment: If you look at the last one, if instead of 5/2 we take 5/4 common, it looks like a+b cubed...

Comment: OK, I see that, but the next to last is not $(a+b)^2$

Comment: Im just saying that it somehow resembles that. And ofcourse the last one by taking 5/4 common doesnt make it a+b cubed.

Comment: Fine, I should have told you all, bit if I had told you all before you might have said only one answer, and I suspect there are two. The actual question from where I got the above is to find the odd one out, and now I think the answer is only the last term. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $[(a+b)^n - a^n - b^n]/ab$, except for powers of 2

Comment: It would help if you could provide some details as to how you derived this in order to guide the OP. Regards

Comment: Rather, it looks like $x_n = c_n\cdot \frac{(a+b)^n-a^n-b^n}{ab}$ with $c_n\in\mathbb R$. From the few terms given, we can observe $c_1=?, c_2=2, c_3=3, c_4=c_5=4$. So this reduces to guessing what the sequence $(c_n)_n$ is (but note that $c_n$ is not always a power of $2$).

Comment: The coefficients were (apart from overall factors), 2,3,2 for one term, then 1,2,2,1 for the next.  That looks vaguely like Pascal's triangle.  2,3,2 looks very like the middle of 1,4,6,4,1 and that is confirmed by the 5,10,10,5 in the next row.

Comment: I first put the terms within each polynomial in order from all $a$ to all $b$.  That's why I said the coefficients were 2,3,2 and not 2,2,3 for the fourth polynomial.

Comment: How did you first get that? And secondly i do not think the relation is right. And if the question had anymore constants, i would not hesitate to put them in the question.