# Is this just a version of the binomial theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

I asked a question related to it and found something interesting (at least that is what I think)...

Here is the link to the original question:
[What is the pattern of this sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422783/what-is-the-pattern-of-this-sequence)

I went through a sequence in which I had to find the wrong term and now I think the correct sequence for it is the following...

$$ 0 , 1 , a+b , a^2 + b^2  + \frac32 ab , a^3 + b^3 + 2ab (a+b),....$$

By the answers I had got, if I represent the term in the above sequence by k and it's position by n, then

$$ (a+b)^n= (a^n)+(b^n)+ (nabK)$$

N is strictly greater than 0.

I think the relation is a bit interesting, but I also think it is all connected by the binomial theorem and all this relation is pure stupidity. Is it so?

Is it that if I take any term from the series and make the equation independent of k(I do not know how), do I get the binomial theorem?

Or it is just a coincidence that almost all terms of the sequence resemble to some powers of $ a+b $?

If you are still not getting the question, I am just asking that why the series is resembling to $$ 0,(a+b)^0,(a+b)^1, ....$$

Comment: I think you should look for a more descriptive title and link the original question. Using LaTex (in the form of MathJax here) would be even better. All this will attract more people and better answers.

Comment: You *think* the correct sequence is ...? How is the sequence defined, where does it occur?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the sequence is given by 
$$ x_n=\frac{(a+b)^n-a^n-b^n}{nab}.$$
If $a=-b$ and $n$ is odd, we observe that $x_n=0$, so its not surprising that the polynomial $x_n$ is divisible by $(a+b)$.
Also, $$n(a+b)x_n =(a+b)((a+b)^{n}-a^n-b^n)=(a+b)^{n+1}-a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}-ab(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})=(n+1)x_{n+1}-ab(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})$$ may explain a lot.

Comment: Firstly, k here is not completely divisible by a+b, it is just that it resembles by a+b squared, cubed, e.t.c. .

Comment: By k I mean x of n

Comment: And I did not understand that how by proving x of n 0 you are sayIng that it is not sup rising that x of n is divisible by a+b. Also, $ x_n $ is not completely divisible by a+b, it just resembles it. To clarify the question, I am just asking why does it resemble to be a power of a+b?